# Is this a proper proof of (-1)(-1) = 1?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am a novice in proof writing and have just started a book on analysis. I have no other pure math experience or knowledge of abstract algebra.

I am trying to prove that $(-1)*(-1) = 1$. I will first show my attempt and follow it with the standard technique that I have found online. I would like to understand why the second method is preferred (or perhaps the only valid one).

***Method 1*** (my attempt): We are given the nine field axioms for $\Bbb R$. Using these, it has been shown (in the text) that $(-1)x = -x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Therefore, $(-1)(-1) = -(-1) = 1$ because we have the identity element of multiplication $1 \in \Bbb R$ and there exists $ -1 \in \Bbb R$ such that $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$.

**Method 2** (found by Google search): We know that $(0)(0) = 0$ because it was shown (in the text) that $0x = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Then $$(0)(0) = ((-1) + 1)*((-1) + 1) = (-1)(-1) + (-1)(1) + (1)(-1) + (1)(1) \\= (-1)(-1) - 1 - 1 + 1 = (-1)(-1) - 1 = 0$$ Therefore $(-1)(-1) = 1$ because we see that $(-1)(-1)$ is the additive inverse of $-1$.

Is the second method simply a more precise version of the first method, while the first is overly verbal? Or is the first somehow using circular reasoning?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your method (I assume that $-(-x)=x$ is known).

Comment: $-(-x)$ isn't just notation for the additive inverse of $-x$?

Comment: $-(-x)$ is notation for the additive inverse of $-x$, but it still needs to be shown (this is admittedly very quick) that this is equal to $x$.  Hagen is just saying that he presumes that's already been done; otherwise, you need to do that as well.

Answer (score 8):

I'd do it directly as follows:

$$(-1)(-1)+(-1)\stackrel{Dist.}=(-1)\left[(-1)+1\right]\stackrel{\text{additive inv.}}=(-1)\cdot 0\stackrel{text}=0$$

Thus, $\;-1\;$ is the additive inverse of $\;(-1)(-1)\;$ , but **also** $\;-(-1)=1\;$ is the additive inverse of $\;(-1)\;$, so by uniqueness of the inverses we're done.

Comment: Thanks! Why do we need to show that (-1)(-1) is the unique inverse?

Comment: @Vale132, we showed it is *an* additive inverse, so by the **axiom** of *uniqueness of additive inverse* (this very axiom existsin any abelian group, if you mind), we conclude it has to be equal to $\;1\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhoZS.jpg ans is in the image attached please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1871647)

Comment: Ok I will keep it in mind as I am new here