# What is the easiest way to rigorously prove that (-1)^2 = 1?

Tags: real-analysis

It's an identity that everyone learns at the very beginning of their math studies, but it itself doesn't seem to be an axiom. The following procedure seems to prove it from the field axioms, but I'm not sure if the second step is cheating:

$$
\begin{split}
(-1)*(-1) &= x &\text{} \\
-(-1) &= x & \quad\text{ (How do you simply justify this unpacking?)}\\
-(-1) + (-1) &= x + (-1) &\text{ }\\
0 &= x + (-1) & \quad\text{ (By the additive inverse property LHS becomes 0)}\\
1 &= x + (-1) + 1 &\text{ }\\
1 &= x & \quad\text{ (Again by the additive inverse)}\\
\end{split}
$$

Is the second line considered rigorous without further justification? And is there a more elegant way to prove this from the field axioms?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783873/is-this-a-proper-proof-of-1-1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use distributivity and that $0 \cdot x=0$ for all x to show that
$$
(-1) \cdot (-1) + (-1)=(-1) \cdot (-1) + (-1) \cdot 1 = (-1) \cdot ((-1)+1)=(-1) \cdot 0=0.
$$
Then
$$
(-1) \cdot (-1) = 1.
$$